# ActionMailer password security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, actionmailer

Am I crazy, or is it a bad idea to keep my SMTP username and password for ActionMailer in the actual (development/production) config file? It seems like I should store it an encrypted place, or at the very minimum, exclude it from my Mercurial pushes.

Right now, I'm just removing the password from my source file before performing a push, but there's got to be a smarter way than the one I'm using. :)

Perhaps I should store it in my database as another user (which is already stored with encrypted passwords) and fetch it programatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an application configuration file **that is not stored in your repository** for storing sensitive information. Here is how I've done it:

1. Add an `app_config.yml` in your `config` directory. Its contents would look like this:

   ```
   smtp_password: kl240jvfslkr32rKgjlk
   some_other_password: 34hg9r0j0g402jg
   and_so_on: lkn$@gJkjgsFLK4gaj
   ```
2. Add a `preinitializer.rb` in your `config` directory with the following contents:

   ```
   require 'yaml'
   APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/config/app_config.yml"))
   ```
3. Substitute your passwords for values in the `APP_CONFIG` variable, like so:

   ```
   smtp_password = kl240jvfslkr32rKgjlk # old version
   smtp_password = APP_CONFIG['smtp_password'] # new version
   ```

Make sure you don't include `app_config.yml` in your repository, though you may want to create an example file that is checked in, just to show a sample of what should be in it. When you deploy your application, make sure that `app_config.yml` is stored on the server. If you're using a standard Capistrano deployment, put the file in the shared folder and update your deployment task to create a symlink to it in the current release's directory.

Comment: That'll work.

BTW, thanks for the screencast regarding ActionMailer and TLS encryption. I used it just earlier today to get it working in my app. Quality stuff.

Comment: Excellent answer Jimmy, this is a great way to abstract any various settings and whatnot that you don't want to store in your DB or have land in your repo... thanks.

Comment: Note, preinitializer.rb is no longer available in Rails 3.  For the solution, see http://asciicasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Jimmy's answer is perfect (+1), I would also note that Github has recommended .gitignore files for every language and the Rails one is [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore) Note that it includes config/*.yml so that no config/yml file is in the respository to begin with. Probably a good move.

Use Capistrano to ask for these things upon deploy:setup the same way you should be doing for your database stuff:

```
task :my_silly_task do 
    sendgrid_password = Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("Sendgrid password: ")
    require 'yaml'
    spec =  {... whatever yaml you need -- probably what Jimmy said...}
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config" 
    put(spec.to_yaml, "#{shared_path}/config/mailer_config.yml") 
end
```