# Is it possible to make a open source app for facebook?

Tags: facebook, open-source

My question is very simple and it's in the title:
"Is it possible to make a open source app for Facebook?"

If so, how do you manage things in the app which are supposed to be private (like the `api_id` I think)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, of course. You just keep things like your `app_id` outside of your source repository (i.e. you have to manually copy it to your host server, to keep it out of the public eye).

This is how you would run any open source application that has "secrets" - which is a lot of them. You just put a dummy file in its place that says something like, "Put your secrets in this file", and you're done. Don't over think it. :D

See the question, [ActionMailer password security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368139/actionmailer-password-security), for a specific example.